# SystemEvents.SessionSwitch Crashes in Windows 8 but works in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, screen-lock, systemevent

I am developing a `WPF` App and getting a very weird problem:

I use `SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;` to detect the screen lock event of the computer. The code works well in `Windows 10`. But crashes in `Windows 8`. The error window I got was "You App has stopped working" without any exception code. I tried it on other `Windows 10` and other `Windows 8` and got the same results. Any ideas?

Comment: use remote debugger to debug your app on win8

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks but it doesn't work..

Comment: what doesn't work? do you get an error message? please post more details.

Comment: It still crashed without any error code. But I've fixed it by downloading a NVIDIA Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why someone downvoted this question. Anyway, I've fixed the problem by installing  [341.61-quadro-grid-desktop-notebook-win8-win7-64bit-international-whql.exe](https://www.driverscloud.com/en/services/GetInformationDriver/45410-280810/nvidia-34161-quadro-grid-desktop-notebook-win8-win7-64bit-international-whqlexe)  on windows 8.